# "\n" is printed in superuser.com question listing on profile page

Tags: bug, status-completed, questions

I noticed that **"\n"** is printed in superuser.com listing on user profile page.

I think that "\n" is printed for the questions who have **"Have you considered accepting an answer or starting a bounty for this question?"** text.

I don't know where to report bug for superuser, so I am just reporting it here.

---

**Screenshot**

[image]
<sub>(source: [flickr.com](https://farm3.static.flickr.com/2511/3820318410_caa0fc9e1f_o.jpg))</sub>

Comment: It's not '/n' ,it's '\n'.

Comment: This is the correct place to report this bug. But John is right: it's a backslash.

Comment: It's a feature.

Comment: I noticed this also.

Comment: @John: you're right, it was typo by me. :)

Comment: The issue not resolved, yet. 8 hours I reported this issue, strange no one in SO team is worried about this... :) That's coooool :)

Comment: What browser was this on?

Comment: Well, I'm sure someone on the SO team wants to fix it, but it's probably not the most urgent thing on their list.

Comment: But don't you know, in the world of bugs and feature-requests, everything is URGENT!

Answer (score 4):

It appears as if it is tied to the "Have you considered accepting an answer or starting a bounty for this question?" string.

That string probably has "\n" at the end.

Answer (score 2):

Same on SO proper.